# Change container size in a template from the Marketplace

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

I am trying to use a template from the Azure Marketplace. Everything works, but it defaults to storage sizes that are by orders of magnitude too large for my usecase.

At the end of the process, I can "kind of" export the template files in text form - at  least parameters and variables, but there are no values for the storage here. I assume that those are hard coded inside whatever scripts they use internally to deploy that application. I see no way to have a look at or modify those scripts.

Is there something that can be done in such a case? Should the scripts behind marketplace apps be available somewhere (I just didn't see them)? Or are they usually closed off from the user?

Answer (score -1):

According to https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/container-apps-now-available-in-the-azure-marketplace/ it seems to be possible to define the storage-size when a container-app is chosen.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, but that article is from 2015, and the question has nothing to do with container apps...